# SVN repository manager with Access Control

Tags: svn

My work currently uses SVN to manage the various coding projects we work on. Currently I have to manage the SVN repositories via Command Line, and as we use `svn+ssh` to access our repositories, we need SSH users on the box and it just gets complicated when staff join/leave or we have to open specific repositories to outside contractors.

What I am after is an SVN Repository manager script/program that I can install (ideally linux-based), which will allow me to manage all our repositories and set access control for different users/groups - and restricted IP address access if possible.

Any suggestions as to scripts I can look at to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can install [Indefero](http://www.indefero.net) on your server. You will be able to easily manage the access rights to your repositories. The only drawback is that the ssh+svn approach is not available, but it's easy to get the Apache setup running (you have Ubuntu/RPMs if needed).

Comment: We don't need ssh+svn, it is just what we currently use. Thanks, I will check out Indefero.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at SVN access manager here: 
http://svn-access-mana.sourceforge.net/#overview

or here: http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Version-Control/SVN-Access-Manager-40105.shtml

Answer (score 0):

The solution I'm aware of for your problem is to host your project using Apache with libapache-svn and [WebSVN](http://www.websvn.info/) with users setup in a htpasswd file.  You are able to push and pull from the http address, as well as add/remove users and even create user groups for fine grain control.  In addition, you have the power of Apache or IIS

Be sure to read through the documentation before doing anything.  libapach2-svn and WebSVN has a quite large feature set that has several minor hiccups that you may get stuck on.  It's a bit tricky to setup, but once you're there, it's extremely flexible.

Review [this](http://alephzarro.com/blog/2007/01/07/installation-of-subversion-on-ubuntu-with-apache-ssl-and-basicauth/) tutorial for a guide to set up Apache and Subversion, and then simply add WebSVN over the top of it.